# JS - Приложение

Tags: javascript

Всем  доброго времени суток. 
В backbone js  есть возможность  структурировать вид.

```
var view ={
   events:{
     "click #id_item":'myfun'
   },
   myfun:function(evt){
    console.log('myfun');
   }
}
```

Как реализовать родителя  на чистом js  чтобы он понимал данную конструкцию
?

Comment: _Как это реализовать родителя на чистом js_ еще раз что?

Comment: в backbone  понравилась данная реализация . Хочу  разобраться как все это работает .  с js  пока только знакомлюсь .  описана структура  отлова евентов  - как ее подключить к коду и заставить  работать. Для начала можно  с backbone .  ( без роутинга )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var view ={
   events:{
     "click #id_item":'myfun'
   },
   myfun:function(evt){
    console.log('myfun');
   }
};

function setEvents(model){
  // Тут всякие проверки, опустим для наглядности
  Object.keys(model.events).forEach(part => {
    // Разделяем событие и селектор (т. к. селектор может содержать пробелы, собираем оставшиеся кусочки и склеиваем их)
    let [eventName, ...selector] = part.split(' ');
    selector = selector.join(' ');
    
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    
    // Если по селектору ничего не нашли - выход
    if(element === null) return;
    
    // Навешивание слушателя
    // Довольно странно что методы не лежат в отдельном ключе типа methods
    element.addEventListener(eventName, model[model.events[part]]);
  });
}

setEvents(view);
```

```html
<div>
  <span id='id_item'>Я тут</span><br />
  <span id='something'>Это не я</span>
</div>
```